# Integer.toString() always returns 1 as length for password box

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans

I am creating a JLabel integrated inside a JOptionPane to input the user's credit card CCV. A password field is also used to blur out the CCV digits. To validate the CCV, I used the if statement: `if (digits.length() == 3)` but it always returns a digit length of 1 from the line  `System.out.println(digits.length());`.The program thinks that its length is 1, even though I entered 3 digits.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

```
JPasswordField jpf = new JPasswordField(3);
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Enter Your CCV: ");
        Box password_box = Box.createHorizontalBox();
        password_box.add(label);
        password_box.add(jpf);
        int ccv = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this, password_box, "Enter CCV", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
        String digits = Integer.toString(ccv);
           
                              
                              if (digits.length() == 3)
                              {
                                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Payment Successful!");
                              }
                              
                              else 
                              {
                              System.out.println(digits.length());
                                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Invalid CCV!", "Invalid Details!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                           }
```

Comment: You are using an OK/Cancel dialog.

Comment: Try `showInputDialog` unstead of `showConfirmDialog`.

Comment: @Yevgen `showInputDialog` contains a simple input field, without any masking. For passwords, this setup is good - it's the result handling that needs to change (see my answer).

Comment: BTW, it's `CVV`, not `CCV`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`showConfirmDialog` doesn't return the number that was entered. It returns a constant that represents what button the user clicked. With your requested option type it's either `JOptionPane.OK_OPTION` (0), `JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION` (2) or `JOptionPane.CLOSED_OPTION` (-1). The latter is when the user clicks away the dialog.

To read the CCV, read the contents of `jpf` when the result of `showConfirmDialog` is `JOptionPane.OK_OPTION`. For any other option, do whatever you need when the user wants to cancel.